# Joomla submenu link takes first level alias

Tags: joomla

In Joomla 3.6 let's say a menu with this structure (menu->submenu)

```
Menu (alias = main-menu)
-->Submenu-1 (alias = submenu-1)
-->Submenu-2 (alias = submenu-2)
```

the flink (or route) of submenus become
*domain.com/main-menu/submenu-1, domain.com/main-menu/submenu-2*

I want to use the submenu alias alone without adding *main-menu/*
to get *domain.com/submenu-1*

how can I fix it ?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can create another menu in menu manager - call it for example 'Hidden Menu', and create there Submenu-1 element [it needs to be 1 level element - not a child].

Then in your 'Main Menu' create item Submenu-1 [as child] - set it type to 'menu item alias', and select your Submenu-1 item from Hidden menu.

so structure will look

```
Hidden Menu
|- Submenu-1 (menu item)

Main Menu
|- parent
|-- Submenu-1 (menu item alias)
```

Comment: Yes it is a solution , thank you

But a lot to do for nothing, an alias should be unchanged